# cannot connect to git server repo from git plugin in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

This can be found repetitive one but I am not getting solution even after exploring similar question.
I have setup Gitlab and Jenkins on same server with 
I have installed plugin for git. Getting error for different tried combinations URL with credentials.

URL tried:

```
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/gitlab-satellites/root/myproject.git
git@localhost:8077/root/myproject.git
http://<myIP or localhost or 127.0.0.1>:8077/root/myproject.git

Credentials used
root user
created one new user from jenkins
gitlab user who is member for same project.
```

Or Does it sounds due to proxy issue?
Or due to some user management or permissions?

Anything you want more please comment.
I request help for same.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the error displayed in your capture, if you want to connect your jenkins to a local Git repository, then you should use the `file://` protocol. In your case, it should be : `file:///var/opt/gitlab/git-data/gitlab-satellites/root/myproject.git`

But, if the gitlab instance is running and serving git repositories, you should be able to use the `http://127.0.0.1:8077/root/myproject.git` (which is probably the url you get when going on the default page of the gitlab project) (it should works, I have the same config here, and it works flawlessly).

Yet, if jenkins is still not able to do the extraction, try to do it alone, by using the standard git clone command on the server : `git clone http://127.0.0.1:8077/root/myproject.git` .
It will probably give you more detailled errors if something is badly configured.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer but steps have not worked. As per your suggestion
`git clone http://127.0.0.1:8077/root/myproject.git` I tried so it is giving such error.
`+ git clone http://127.0.0.1:8077/root/icost.git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'icost'.: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE `

Comment: @Kunal `permission denied` is a "good" thing, if it was Jenkins user doing this, maybe the directory used as workspace is not allowing jenkins user to create directories, change the workspace or check the rights with a `chmod`

Comment: @Julien
No luck. I have given permission 777 to myproject repo but still getting same error after permission like`drwxrwxrwx. 3 jenkins jenkins 18 Jun 22 12:57 myproject`
Error
`Failed to connect to repository : Command "/bin/git ls-remote -h http://127.0.0.1:8077/root/myproject.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'http://127.0.0.1:8077/root/myproject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 407`

Comment: little addition to above question if I want to clone code from server with script then which command should I need?
If git clone http://127.0.0.1:8077/root/myproject.git used it works.
But now I dont want to put it there. New location will be /opt/project/myproject.git